# Why am I recieving this error?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I am trying to setup a mysql database to capture the information from an html form, but when I test it, it comes back with the below error.  The file is located on the same server as the database. My php is located below the error.

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'inmoti6_ted_seminar'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/westcl5/public_html/drjseminars.com/thankyou.php on line 92
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'inmoti6_ted_seminar'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

```
if( $_POST )
        {
          $con = mysql_connect("localhost","inmoti6_ted_seminar","Polarbear5");

          if (!$con)
          {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }

          mysql_select_db("inmoti6_westcl5_ted_sem", $con);

          $users_firstName = $_POST['first_name'];
          $users_lastName = $_POST['last_name'];
          $users_street = $_POST['street'];
          $users_street2 = $_POST['street2'];
          $users_city = $_POST['city'];
          $users_state = $_POST['state'];
          $users_zip = $_POST['zip'];
          $users_country = $_POST['country'];
          $users_email = $_POST['email'];
          $users_telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
          $users_practice = $_POST['practice'];

          $users_firstName = mysql_real_escape_string($users_firstName);
          $users_lastName = mysql_real_escape_string($users_lastName);
          $users_street = mysql_real_escape_string($users_street);
          $users_street2 = mysql_real_escape_string($users_street2);
          $users_city = mysql_real_escape_string($users_city);
          $users_state = mysql_real_escape_string($users_state);
          $users_zip = mysql_real_escape_string($users_zip);
          $users_country = mysql_real_escape_string($users_country);
          $users_email = mysql_real_escape_string($users_email);
          $users_telephone = mysql_real_escape_string($users_telephone);
          $users_practice = mysql_real_escape_string($users_practice);

          $query = "
          INSERT INTO `westcl5_ted_sem`.`ted_seminar` (`First Name`, `Last Name`, `E-mail`, `Phone #`, `Street Address`, `Street Address 2`, `City`, `State`, `Zip Code`, `Country`, `Practice`) VALUES ('$users_firstName', '$users_lastName', '$users_email', '$users_telephone', '$users_street', '$users_street2', '$users_city', '$users_state', '$users_zip', '$users_country', '$users_practice');";

          mysql_query($query);

          mysql_close($con);
        }
```

Comment: It seems your database user has not enough permission, give your user required permission

Comment: And also take note, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Stop using them as it isn't secure anymore. Look into `PDO` or `MySQLi` :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your password which is not matching. try defulat 
$con=mysql_connect("localhost",'root',''); instead of 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","inmoti6_ted_seminar","Polarbear5");

while working on XAMPP  i was also received this error, but by using above line which i mention there solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to give the `inmoti6_ted_seminar` user permissions. Log in as root to the mysql server and execute the following SQL, you can of course set which permissions they have, but I assumed you just wanted `INSERT`.

```
CREATE USER 'inmoti6_ted_seminar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Polarbear5';
GRANT INSERT ON inmoti6_westcl5_ted_sem.* TO 'inmoti6_ted_seminar'@'localhost';
```